# Error SQL syntax in the middle of a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When i click the insert button, my program always tell me that i have a SQL syntax error near CPF, but the error starts in the middle of the textbox, just as i write 190.890.567-45 in the text box and the program tells me that the error is near '567-45', here is the code:

```
    private void btninserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sql;
        int numero;

        sql = "select * from doador where CPF = " + txtCPF.Text;
        DataTable dt = bd.executarconsulta(sql);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Doador já cadastrado!!!!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {

            if (txtNome.Text != "" || txtCel.Text != "" || txtCPF.Text != "" || txtEndereco.Text != "" || txtTelRe.Text != "" || int.TryParse(txtIdade.Text, out numero))
            {
                bd.ConectarBD();
                sql = "INSERT INTO DOADOR(CPF, NOME, IDADE, TELCASA, TELCELULAR, ENDERECO) VALUES('" + txtCPF.Text + "','" + txtNome.Text + "'," + txtIdade.Text + ",'" + txtTelRe.Text + "','" + txtCel.Text + "','" + txtEndereco.Text + "')";
                bd.executarcomandos(sql);
                MessageBox.Show("Doador Cadastro com sucesso!!!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Valor Invalido!!!!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtCPF.BackColor = Color.Red;
                txtNome.BackColor = Color.Red;
                txtEndereco.BackColor = Color.Red;
                txtIdade.BackColor = Color.Red;
                txtTelRe.BackColor = Color.Red;
                txtCel.BackColor = Color.Red;
                txtCPF.Focus();
            }

        }
    }
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBDNX.png)

Comment: Don't use string concatenation! Use parameters!

Comment: What error returns?

Comment: Your delimiters between your text box strings are all wrong.

Comment: What are the correct ones ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just add `'`between text param in SQL. Like this:
`sql = "select * from doador where CPF = '" + txtCPF.Text + "'";`

Comment: not really a good solution. but instead, suggest to use parameters.

Comment: how to use paramaters ?

Comment: Come on, who click the unprove. they are freshmen, just let them get the point, it's a long way, they'll get there someday. PS: who still use SQL string opreate database, use ORM eg EntityFramework. and i don't like parameters, it's make no diffrence but Complicated, those SQL string barely change after wrote.

Comment: @CaioVieira, it's hard to give an example when you haven't indicated what DBMS you're using, but [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) contains a simple example of parameters for SQL Server.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie thank you my friend, i appreciate the answer, but i already solved the problem, i use MySql.

Comment: @CaioVieira, are you using parameters with MySql? I'd strongly recommend you look into it - it protects you from SQL injection and also helps your database to tune for common queries.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie man, i dont really know the meaning of paramaters, is parameters each column on a row of the data table ? And what is SQL Injection ?

Comment: @CaioVieira, with parameters, your statement would look like `INSERT INTO DOADOR(CPF, NOME ...) VALUES (@CPF, @NOME ...)`, then you would supply `@CPF` and `@NOME` as parameters to the query (usually your command object will have a method like [`AddParameterWithValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)). Imagine what would happen with your current implementation if someone enters `'` into one of your textboxes. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations) for details on SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, either by accident or maliciously. [This xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/327/) gives a good example of what can happen if your database input isn't protected...